# Should I use Boot-Repair if I can see Grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I have a [Dell XPS 9550](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/docs) (with an NVIDIA graphics card) on which I had been happily been dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 LTS before I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 20 LTS last month.  The upgrade seemed to complete successfully, but since then I can only boot into my Windows 10 instance.  GRUB loads, and when I select Ubuntu it simply shows a black screen indefinitely.  If I attempt to load into recovery mode, I freeze at "Loading initial ramdisk...".

For what it is worth, the same thing happens when I attempt to run Ubuntu 20.04 from a USB drive in UEFI mode-- I get a black screen.  If I enable Legacy ROM loading, I can get Ubuntu 20.04 to load on my machine from the USB drive.  My Ubuntu 18.04 USB loads/runs Ubuntu with no problems in UEFI mode.

Things I have tried include:

- editing the start script and removing `splash` and `quiet` - same result
- editing the start script and adding `nomodeset` - same result
- editing the start script and adding `nouveau.modeset=0` - same result
- Updating my machine's BIOS - same result

Since GRUB *is* loading, is this a good scenario for running [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to see if it resolves my issue?  Or are there better alternatives to try to get my Ubuntu back?

Comment: With nVidia, you have to remove/purge old nVidia driver (and any ppa) before update, use nomodeset to boot new version & add new nVidia drivers. You also have to purge nVidia driver before installing new one or you get conflicts as new driver, does not automatically remove old one.  Issue is after what Boot-Repair report normally shows. Do not switch to Legacy if UEFI install that just creates more issues. I always do a new install to a new / (root) 30GB partition with all data in separate partition(s), so I can confirm new version works well with my system. can you boot old kernel?

Comment: @oldfred - thanks for your guidance.  My Grub menu shows two kernel options in the "advanced options" menu: `5.4.0-48-generic` and `4.15.0-118-generic`, both with standard and recovery options.  Both recovery options with no edits freeze at "Loading initial ramdisk...".  Attempting to edit the recovery options to replace `nomodeset` with `nouveau.modeset=0` yields the same result.

Comment: @oldfred - FWIW, I suspect as though the inability to load from USB in UEFI mode may be related to the inability to load from grub; but I haven't seen any posts addressing this with resolutions that worked for me.

Comment: if newer Ubuntu do you use Safe Graphic boot mode, or else add nomodeset when using grub. Replace quiet splash on linux line with nomodeset.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, unfortunately I tried replacing `quiet` and `splash` with `nomodeset` as part of my troubleshooting prior to posting the question, and it did not cause any change in the symptoms I observed.

Comment: Dell normally works well. But I stopped doing upgrades and only do a new install to a new partition keeping old install for a while. But install partition is 30GB with all data in other partitions(s), so have lots of room on my drives for installs. Ubuntu 16 on the DELL XPS15 9550 Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345444